# How to change the state of another reducer inside of the extraReducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Say I have the following lifecycle actions.

```js
builder
  .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.isLoading = true;
  }).addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.isLoading = false;
    state.user = action.payload;
    // Change the Page to HomePage - using the location state from navigationSlice
    toast.success('Logged In User!');
  }).addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
    state.isLoading = false;
    toast.error(action.payload);
  });
```

I want to invoke the `setLocation` reducer that changes the state value from the navigation reducer. Take a look.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { getCurrentPageLocation } from '../../utils';

const initialState = {
  location: getCurrentPageLocation()
};

const navigationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'navigation',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLocation: (state, action) => {
      state.location = action.payload;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {

  }
});

export const { setLocation } = navigationSlice.actions;

export default navigationSlice.reducer;
```

How can I invoke the `setLocation` method inside of the `extraReducers` (`loginUser.fulfilled`)? Now I know I can just dispatch this using the `thunkAPI` in the `createAsyncThunk` but I don't like doing that. I want to be able to invoke it straight from the `extraReducers` and preferably without importing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducers are still pure functions in Redux-Toolkit, so there is not anything you can do from the `loginUser.fulfilled` reducer. Add an extra case in the `navigationSlice` state slice to handle the dispatched `loginUser.fulfilled` action.

Example:

```js
const navigationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'navigation',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLocation: (state, action) => {
      state.location = action.payload;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.location = /* update */
      });
  }
});
```